# Creating a Dialog component and showing/hiding from parent

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

In Vue/Vuetify, how do we hide/show dialogs from parent? I'm trying to use `v-model` and here is a simplified version of my setup:

Parent component (just a button that triggers the child component to show)

```
<template>
<div>
    <v-btn class="ma-2" outlined fab color="red" small @click.stop="editItem()">
        <v-icon size="16">mdi-close-circle</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
    <user-dialog v-model="dialog" :eitem="editedItem" class="elevation-2" />
</div>
</template>

<script>
import UserDialog from "./UserDialog.vue";
export default {
    components:{
        UserDialog
    },
    data() {
        return {
            counter: 0,
            dialog: false,
            editedItem: {},
        }
    },
    methods: {
        editItem: function() {            
            this.counter++;       
            this.editedItem = Object.assign({}, {
                title: 'some title' + this.counter,
                details: 'some details for this item'
            });        

            this.dialog = true;
        },
    },
}
</script>
```

Child component (basically a dialog box)

```
<template>
    <v-dialog v-model="value" max-width="500px">
        <v-card>
            <v-card-title>
                <span class="headline">A Dialog</span>
            </v-card-title>

            <v-card-text>
                <v-container grid-list-md>
                    <v-layout wrap>
                        <v-flex xs12>
                            <v-text-field v-model="eitem.title" label="Title"></v-text-field>
                        </v-flex>
                        <v-flex xs12>
                            <v-text-field v-model="eitem.details" label="Details"></v-text-field>
                        </v-flex>
                    </v-layout>
                </v-container>
            </v-card-text>

            <v-card-actions>
                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                <v-btn color="blue darken-1" text @click.stop="save">Save</v-btn>
                <v-btn color="blue darken-1" text @click.stop="close">Cancel</v-btn>
            </v-card-actions> 
        </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            value: Boolean, 
            eitem: Object,
        },
        data() {
            return {
                editedItem: this.eitem,
            }
        },
        methods: {
            save() {
                //perform save
                this.$emit('input', false);
            },
            close() {
                this.$emit('input', false);
            },
        },
    }
</script>
```

This setup works, but give the following warning:

> Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "value"

But if act upon this advice and declare a `data` item in the child component and set `v-model` of the `v-dialog` to this data item, the dialog stops showing up upon click.

I perhaps understand why it does that, but cannot figure out a proper way of fixing this that doesn't show warnings. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Instead of using `v-model` bind the `v-text-field`'s value to the prop. And on `input` emit a custom event to the parent and let it update the prop's value. You can use a computed property with a getter/setter.

Comment: @HusamIbrahim: I hear that `v-model` is a syntactic sugar that does **exactly the thing** that you described. How'd that approach be different?

Comment: Just to clarify, those text-field bindings are not the issue at hand right now. I'm actually struggling with the `v-dialog`'s `v-model` at the moment. The gist of the problem in my understanding is that I need a way to bind a local `data` item with a `prop`, so that whenever the parent component changes its bound data item, the child component is notified about this change and in response the child component updates its local data item (which will then trigger v-dialog to appear or disappear..

Comment: The difference is that `v-model` will attempt to directly modify the value on input and that's the equivalent of `@input="value=$event.target.value"`. What you want is to emit a custom event to the parent via `@input="()=>{$emit('updateValue', newValue}"` and have the parent listen for an `updateValue` event to update the value of the prop. That will automatically be reflected in the child component after update.

Comment: I see that you declare `value` as a prop to be used with `v-dialog` but you don't pass it's value from the parent. In that case you should specify a default value. And instead of using `v-model` on the value directly use a computed property with a getter/setter. That way if a value is passed from the parent you can emit a custom event to the parent to update the prop's value. Otherwise you can update a local value instead.

Comment: @HusamIbrahim: Hmm... this second suggestion sounds interesting. Can u plz post an answer with suggested edits in my code above?

Comment: I'm on mobile right now. I'll see if I can post an answer when I get home. But in the meantime you can look at @EvilArthas answer below as it does point you in the right direction. You just have to initialize your values properly and handle `undefined` conditions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Vue throws a warning when you mutate `props`, you should not use `v-model` with `props`. To handle this use the following pattern:

```
computed: {
  propModel: {
    get () { return this.value },
    set (value) { this.$emit('input', value) },
  },
},
```

Define `computed` property with getter, that returns `props.value`, and setter that emits `input` event (that will be successfully handled in parent, since you use `v-model`)

Don't forget to chage your `template`:
`<v-dialog v-model="propModel" max-width="500px">`

Answer (score 1):

This works for me and do not need to create a computed data.

```
<v-dialog
    width="600px"
    :value="value"
    @input="$emit('input', $event)"
  >
    
</v-dialog>
```